# French excel numbers being changed to english when uploaded to SharePoint, how to fix?

Tags: excel

I have a site where I've uploaded an excel document that was translated by one of the companies we use and once I uploaded it to my SharePoint site but the column that contained numbers changed to english, so instead of 1234,56 it is now 1,234.56 which is incorrect for the needs of this document. It happens with all the excel documents that contain numbers. We've tried changing it in the document but it won't stay as the french numbers.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem, or what's causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you check your regional settings of SharePoint site? Is it the same as Excel file? Check it out: "Site Actions" -> "Site Settings" -> "Regional settings" under "Site Administration" section.

Hope it helps,

Andrew

Comment: Nice to hear this. Glad that it helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

Data formats (date,currency,names, time Zones.......) that are displayed by SharePoint basically comply with the LOCALE settings of the site.

```
Change you site's regional settings to French as pointed above.
```